# InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException and SQLGrammarException

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, exception, sqlexception

When i am trying to update the hibernate entity, i am getting this exceptions. What could be the problem?

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {
...
@Override
public void updateAllStock() {
    products.getAllProducts().stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getUnitsInStock() < 500)
            .forEach(e -> products.updateStock(e.getProductId(), 
                       1000));
}
```

DAO

```
@Repository
public class ProductDaoImpl implements ProductDao {
...
@Override
public void updateStock(int productId, int numOfUnits) {
    Session currentSession = factory.getCurrentSession();
    Product product = currentSession.load(Product.class, productId);
    product.setUnitsInStock(product.getUnitsInStock() + numOfUnits);
}
```

EDIT: Adding Stack trace :

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'condition='New', description='Apple iPhone 6s smartphone with 4.00-inch 640x1136' at line 1
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:942)
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3966)
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3902)
```

I suppose that there are any problems with hibernate configuration or?

Comment: The stack trace of the exception tells you what the problem is. Read it. If you can't understand it, post it.

Comment: @JBNizet added stacktrace

Comment: You added the beginning of the stack trace. The remaning contains the root cause of the exception, containing the error message of the JDBC driver. Reading the genrated SQL query that is being executed and is ivalid would also help you figuring out the problem.

Comment: @JBNizet changed the stack trace, but what could be the problem, the condition is Varchar(90) and description is Varchar(255)

Comment: `condition` is a reserved keyword: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-7-detailed-C. Change the name of that column.

Comment: @JBNizet yes, thank you!